# Examples of open and bounded sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$ satisfying the uniform cone condition

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Cone conditions on domains are extensively used in the proof of the Sobolev embedding theorem. Somewhat less common in that respect is the uniform cone condition, which Adams and Fournier (Sobolev spaces, 2001) define as follows[image]

Here, $\Omega_{\delta}$ refers to the set of points in $\Omega$ within $\delta$-distance of the boundary of $\Omega$, i.e.,
$$\Omega_{\delta} = \{ x \in \Omega: \text{dist}(x, \text{boundary} \{\Omega\} < \delta \} $$

I am having a bit of trouble digesting all these requirements, so my question would be: are there any simple enough examples of open and bounded domains satisfying the uniform cone property? It would seem to me that many domains in $\mathbb{R}^d$, such as the unit squares $(0,1)^d$, do not fulfil these requirements, but the unit ball $\{x:||x|| <1\}$ does. Is my intuition correct?

Comment: The hypercube does satisfy this assumption. Why do you think it does not?

Comment: @daw Because its boundary is not smooth and, as I understand it, smoothness and uniform cone conditions are almost equivalent.

Comment: In Adams book it is said that bounded domains have this property iff the boundary is locally Lipschitz. Which is true for the cube.

Comment: @daw Can you please expand your comment as necessary and post it as an answer?